# Table variables in in-memory oltp procedure

Tags: azure-sql-database, in-memory-database, in-memory-oltp

Can I use table variable in memory optimized procedure?

```
DECLARE @tvTableD TABLE  
    ( Column1   INT   NOT NULL ,  
      Column2   CHAR(10) );
```

Here it says, no.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/transact-sql-constructs-not-supported-by-in-memory-oltp?view=sql-server-2017#natively-compiled-stored-procedures-and-user-defined-functions

Can someone please confirm the same?

Answer (score 0):

You linked the doc:

"Table types cannot be declared inline with variable declarations. Table types must be declared explicitly using a CREATE TYPE statement."

This article shows you how to replace the inline table variable declaration with a table type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.typeTableD  
    AS TABLE  
    (  
        Column1  INT   NOT NULL   INDEX ix1,  
        Column2  CHAR(10)  
    )  
    WITH  
        (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON);
```

[Faster temp table and table variable by using memory optimization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/faster-temp-table-and-table-variable-by-using-memory-optimization?view=sql-server-2017)